# Strange PNG errors: Bad length for IHDR chunk

Tags: java, png, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Heres the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error reading PNG header!
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readHeader(PNGImageReader.java:307)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata(PNGImageReader.java:637)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1212)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1560)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1282)
    at Bundle.iconExists(Bundle.java:139)
    at Bundle.dPhIconExists(Bundle.java:158)
    at BundleAnalyzer.supports6(BundleAnalyzer.java:14)
    at TheifReader.<init>(TheifReader.java:14)
    at TheifReader.main(TheifReader.java:63)
Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Bad length for IHDR chunk!
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readHeader(PNGImageReader.java:239)
    ... 10 more
```

and heres the code causing it:

```
        bimg = ImageIO.read(icons[i]);
```

icons is an array of files. The strange thing is that my computer can read the images just fine in any image viewer. Googling the error gave me no results. I have a ton of images I need to read, so is their an alternate way to get the dimensions of an image aside from turning it into a BufferedImage? Will that fix the problem? Is there a way to fix these images? I got them from collecting icons of apps from iOS devices. Tests from my own devices produced no errors, though ones that had previously been sent as part of a zip file, though gathered the same way, produced this error regularly. Everything I know about compression tells me this shouldn't happen. I am not sure where to begin looking, and really need a fix.  [Here is an example of a failed image](https://mega.co.nz/#!b1gS0aJZ!XnoJIlUd6wVw4nu203gENxMJVol-5bmU2Rwmnf-c2YQ).

I should note, for this part of my program, all I need are the image dimensions. I believe this can be obtained through reading metadata, but I also cannot find specifics on this with java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [PNG specifiaction](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/png-1.2-pdg.html#C.Critical-chunks):

> **4.1.1. IHDR Image header**
>
> The IHDR chunk must appear FIRST.

Your example image contains a custom critical chunk `CgBI` as the first chunk, and does not conform to this spec. This is why you get the exception.

Actually, it seems your image is an "iOS optimized PNG".

From http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/CgBI:

> It is not compatible with PNG. Standard PNG decoders that don't support it will fail gracefully, due to an unknown "critical chunk".

Now, what probably should be considered a bug in the `com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader` is that it doesn't check that the first chunk is actually a `IHDR`chunk, before claiming it can read the input.

You can fix the images, by reading them in one of the viewers/apps you say can read them fine, then writing them back as normal PNGs. I tested using Preview on OS X, and it worked fine. Give it a try.

If on OS X (with dev tools), you should also be able to use Apple's modified pngcrush with the following command line:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos pngcrush -revert-iphone-optimizations infile.png outfile.png
```

---

If you just want to get the width/height of the images, you don't need to read full `BufferedImages`, just get an `ImageReader` and use its `getWidth(0)` and `getHeight(0)` methods (there are plenty examples on SO for this already, no need to repeat).

You could probably also create a quick PNG structure parser, that skips the `CgBI` chunk, and parses the `IHDR` directly, to get  width/height.

Comment: That chunk, and its **illegal** position, is an indication the PNG has been fried by Apple's proprietary build of `pngcrush`. Try my own [`pngdefry`](http://www.jongware.com/pngdefry.html). If contains alpha, this got premultiplied; `pngdefry` will also restore it.

Comment: .. after defrying, `pngcheck` complains "illegal (unless recently approved) unknown, public chunk" `iDOT`. It's also *badly* compressed :) What software created it? (Edit) If you need only its size: `pngdefry` reports this *anyway*, for all kinds of PNGs.

Comment: @Jongware I believe you are right. It's Apple proprietary. And that's the problem, they may change the internal representation at any time... According to [iphonedevwiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format) the zlib header/footer and CRCs are also removed. I guess the CgBI chunk should tell something about what spec violations they have applied, but it's of course undocumented.

Comment: The most poignant point is that PNG experts seem to agree Apple's "optimizations" -- breaking the Standard, and abusing the Open Source/GPL status of `pngcrush` -- are barely worth any computational gains to display these images ... (see f.e. ["You're probably wasting your time"](http://bjango.com/articles/pngcompression/))

Comment: Okay, so would this project work? https://github.com/viphe/ipng-converter I'll try png defry if it wont.

Comment: @user3236716 Don't know. I've given you two options that will work, Jongware another. If you like to explore a different path, feel free. :-)

Comment: @Jongware I believe the use cases/goals for Apple's optimizations and that of (the original) pngcrush or ImageOptim are very different. Apple wants decoding and display performance (and thus improved battery lifetime) over small file size. pngcrush and ImageOptim want smaller file size for fast network transfer.

Comment: I ended up modifying klinworks a bit to process thousands of images in place, and worked with only two errors, on images I don't really care about. Thanks for the help everyone!