# Inconsistent javax.imageio.IIOException: Bad length for IHDR chunk

Tags: java, png, remote-debugging

I currently encounter a very strange error: When I start my application with parameters `-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005` and remotely connect via Eclipse, everything works. When I remove this parameter (nothing else changed), I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error reading PNG header!
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readHeader(PNGImageReader.java:315) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata(PNGImageReader.java:654) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1248) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1606) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1400) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.jgoodies.application.ResourceConverters$DefaultConverter.convertImage(ResourceConverters.java:452) ~[retest.jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Bad length for IHDR chunk!
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readHeader(PNGImageReader.java:247) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Since I really, really didn't change anything else, I do suppose it has nothing to do with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359540/strange-png-errors-bad-length-for-ihdr-chunk), as the image file obviously is undamaged.

Since this is a foreign project for me, it could have to do something with 3rd party libraries or likewise. I am on a Mac, Java 1.8.0_92, if this could be relevant.

Update: If I remove a specific jar file, the problem also goes away. However, then I get `NoClassDefFoundError`s later, so the jar file is needed. Any ideas, suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Is the file a regular PNG file or a special "iPNG" like in the question you're referring to?

Comment: It is a regular PNG file that is stored inside some jar-file and can be opened without any problems if I remove the offending jar from class path or add the remote-debugging parameters...

Comment: Can you share the file that causes the exception? And also the name of the jar/library might help... Note that `ImageIO` is plugin-based, so if the "offending" jar contains one or more `ImageReaderSpi`s, that could explain some of the problem. Also, the extra runtime parameters (or pure coincidence) could possibly change the order of the installed plugins. But that seems a little far-fetched. Strange indeed.

Comment: Wow, this is the hint towards the solution. If I remove the `META-INF/services` folder from the offending jar file, the problem also goes away ... but another one occurs. I am not sure if the are somehow connected, so no final solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve the problem, although I am not completely sure what caused it and why it was a Heisenbug.

The offending jar indeed hat a `ImageReaderSpi` as suggested by [haraldK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1428606/haraldk) in the comment, but it also had some sort of obfuscation runtime-magic in place.